# Splitting angular component file into separate files

Tags: angular

I have an angular component:

**drawComponent**: It has many buttons like draw rectangle, draw circle, etc. I am using paperjs which helps in actual drawing. I have some common objects which get updated. For example, I have a paperjs object which gets updated whenever I draw any shape be it circle, rectangle or any other.

My question is my `drawComponent.component.ts`has become too large with more than 2000 lines of code. In nodejs, I could easily split each function in a separate file, but here in angular I am not sure how to do that. Is there any way I can split my file into separate file based on the functions?

Comment: So many code lines is definitely a "bad smell". Consider removing all business logic into a service or services and possibly making sub-components out of reusable or repeated UI elements in your component.

Comment: FYI: A recent in-house application I developed for maintaining customer account data had ~40 components, ~20 services with the average typescript file size of 43 LOC and a max of 269 LOC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Official file structure guidelines

You should definitely split and organize your logic into smaller files. The official [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#file-structure-conventions) recommends the following principles:

1. **Rule of One**

> Apply the single responsibility principle (SRP) to all components, services, and other symbols. This helps make the app cleaner, easier to read and maintain, and more testable.

2. **Small files**

> Consider limiting files to 400 lines of code. Consider limiting functions to 75 lines of code

---

## How to split functionality across files

1. Split your app into Modules, Components, Services, Directives and Pipes as described in the [Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide).
2. For components, directives and pipes shared across different components or modules, create a [Shared Feature Module](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module)
3. For shared functionality, create [Singleton Services](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#services-are-singletons)
4. If it makes sense for your project, you can simply put some functions, classes or variables into separate files. It's all just TypeScript, [you can export and import things easily](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: wish you write a sample Hello world. example separate component for a path of routes

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to separate the common logic in drawingComponent.abstract.ts and implement the drawing logic in different components (e.g. circle.component.ts, triangle.component.ts) which extends the abstract class.