# In angular 8 how to manage large html file?

Tags: angular

Currently I have started working in one Angular 8 project & I am totally new to Angular 8.

In my current project I have one html file which containing around 2500 lines of code & my task is to make it more manageable by dividing into multiple html files.

So from my R&D, I have found that I need to create extra component with html and ts files to solve my problem but I am curious that has there been any way so that I can just simply create extra html files from my main html file without creating ts file & simply include those extra htmls in my main html file.

Also I would like to know the best way to manage large html files in angular 8 because I have searched online but not found any proper answer.

Note: my main html file has dynamic content.

Thanks.

Comment: Why close vote on my question. Who have voted for close , can you please specify it why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create new component files (ts + html) and include that in you main html file.

You need to use ( @Input / @output ) or Services (with Subject) to pass data/do interaction  with the new created files. (if required).

Comment: thanks. Has there been any way available without generating new component file because creating new component means lots of things to be handled.

Comment: there is no facility as of now to just have html file included in a html in Angular,
you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724044/splitting-angular-component-file-into-separate-files